# Downside of withdrawing you passport

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, passport

Due to domestic problem, I have decided to withdraw my visa application for extending  of my stay from home office which was gone for extension couple of months ago. While my lawyer tell me there won't be any issue. I been told by my family member that When you withdraw it, they stamp "Withdrawal" and update the reason in system thus making it hard to apply again. I am in a kind of limbo because my son will be in uk while I am at other country and think it will be harder for me to get visa for uk. My spouse is a Portuguese national and I am dependent on my partner. 
What should I do?

Comment: Application for what? Passport application? Visa application? Other?

Comment: @Gagravarr extension of my visa.

Comment: What kind of visa?

Comment: @Gagravarr it's a spouse visa and if u ask what sort of spouse visa my partner got its a EEA

Comment: You should edit this information into your question, it will be hard to answer without this!

Comment: Why would a withdrawal make a future application more difficult?  Do you even need to state a reason for the withdrawal?  Just say "I want to withdraw my application."

Comment: @phoog I heard it says "withdrawn" stamp on it. That make it more difficult to get a visa stamp again.

Comment: @Nofel Why would a "withdrawn" stamp make it more difficult?  Furthermore, who are you going to believe, your (presumably qualified and experienced) lawyer, or rumors you've heard from your family members?  Why would you trust people on the internet more than you trust your lawyer?  Or do you have evidence that the rumors are true?  If so, please describe that evidence so it can be addressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an EEA family permit, the criteria for evaluating the application are very minimal, owing to the EU right of free movement.  A future application would only be jeopardized if your withdrawal raises additional suspicions about:

- Whether your family member is an EEA national
- Whether your family member is (or will be) in the UK
- Whether your family member is a "qualified person" or has a permanent right of residence
- Whether your relationship with your family member is genuine
- Whether you pose a threat to public safety, public health, or public policy